# Invoking Twitter on Blackberry Z10 fails

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10

I use the code below to invoke a Twitter share from a contextAction. The code works on our alpha device, but when I trigger the ActionItem on a Z10 device it fails.

I've tried to invoke it from QML, as well as from C++.

C++

```
void Sharer::shareTwitter(QString data) {
    m_pInvocation = Invocation::create(InvokeQuery::create()
        .parent(this)
        .mimeType("text/plain")
        .invokeTargetId("Twitter")
        .data(data.toUtf8()));
    QObject::connect(m_pInvocation, 
        SIGNAL(armed()), this, SLOT(invocationArmed()));
}

void Sharer::invocationArmed() {
    m_pInvocation->trigger("bb.action.SHARE");
}
```

QML

```
InvokeActionItem {
    id: invokeShare
    title: qsTr("Share") + Retranslate.onLocaleOrLanguageChanged
    ActionBar.placement: ActionBarPlacement.OnBar
    image: shareImage.image
    query {
        mimeType: "text/plain"
        invokeActionId: "bb.action.SHARE"
        invokeTargetId: "Twitter"
    }
    onTriggered: {
        data = ListItemData.text
    }
}
```

And the error logged in the console when I try to invoke it is

InvocationWrapper::onQueryFinished: no matching result from Menu Service for query
 mimeType="text/plain"
 uri=QUrl("") 
 data= "Test" 
 metadata= QMap() 
 perimeter= 0 
 action= "" 
 target= "
 invokerIncluded= false 
InvocationPrivate::onQueryResolved: no result matching query, no armed signal sent.

Comment: QML invokation is broken, so don't even try with that. In c++, the only thing that comes to mind is missing URI.

Comment: I added a URI to the InvokeQuery, but it still didn't work. I have all the details as described in the "Sharing text with twitter" section [here](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/invocation/twitter.html), but it's kicking out the same error.